# How to load JSON Data in jQuery-jTable plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-jtable

I am working on creating a table form using [jTable](http://jtable.org/) plugin. It mainly focus for ASP or PHP MVC but I'm trying to implement it with javascript/html and mongo backend.

I went through entire [jTable API documentation](http://jtable.org/ApiReference) and I found out there is possibility of populating json schema api into table, quite similiar in flexigrid.

The code looks like:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#feeds-table').jtable({
              title: 'Accounts',
              pageSize: 15,
              ajaxSettings: {
                  type: 'GET',
                  dataType: 'json'
              },
              actions: {

              },
              fields: {
                  id: {
                      key: true,
                      list: false
                  },
                  username: {
                      title: 'Username',
                      width: '10%'
                  },
                  email: {
                      title: 'Email',
                      width: '10%'
                  },
                  applications: {
                      title: 'Applications',
                      width: '10%'
                  },
                  sites: {
                      title: 'Sites',
                      width: '10%'
                  },
                  verticals: {
                      title: 'Verticals',
                      width: '10%'
                  },
                  roles: {
                      title: 'Roles',
                      width: '10%'
                  },
                  profiles: {
                      title: 'Record date',
                      width: '30%',
                      type: 'date',
                      create: false,
                      edit: false
                  }
              }
          });
      });
```

If anyone can help me to find out where should I use URL property or is there any other method in the API reference to GET the data and display in table. Please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly load JSON data by setting the 'listAction' to a JSON document .

Example:

```
actions: {
  listAction: 'url/file.json',
},
```

Your JSON file needs to have the same fields specified and the next structure:

```
{
 "Result":"OK",
   "Records":[
    {"PersonId":1,"Name":"Benjamin Button","Age":17,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
    {"PersonId":2,"Name":"Douglas Adams","Age":42,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
    {"PersonId":3,"Name":"Isaac Asimov","Age":26,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"},
    {"PersonId":4,"Name":"Thomas More","Age":65,"RecordDate":"\/Date(1320259705710)\/"}
   ]
}
```

The common way is to point the 'listAction' to a server side script (PHP,ASP.NET...) that return the above JSON object.

Check the `listAction` API reference for more information:
[ApiReference-listAction](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference#act-listAction)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `addRecord` action.  It gives you the option to specify `clientOnly: true` which will prevent jtable from making a server call when you edit a row.
More Information  - [jtable.org-addRecord](http://jtable.org/ApiReference#met-addRecord)