# How to populate jtable faster from External JSON file?

Tags: json, jquery-jtable

I'm populating Jtable from a large JSON file. It takes too much time to populate and render. Is there any to make it fast.

I'm using below function to populate data to Jtable.

```
_addRecordsToTable: function (records) {
           var self = this;
        self._hideBusy();
        $.each(records, function (index, record) {
            self._addRowToTable(self._createRowFromRecord(record));
        });

        self._refreshRowStyles();
    }
```

Please Help.

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418613/how-to-load-json-data-in-jquery-jtable-plugin)

Comment: Thanks. the link you've given is load json data to jtable which is already did.But I've large json it takes too much time to load.How to reduce the time load.